# COOKIES not available on sub-domain in DJANGO inspite using CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

Tags: python, django, cookies, cross-domain, subdomain

I am trying to access the cookies that are set by my domain in my sub-domain site.

I am using django-cors-headers to achieve the same.

I have been able to make request to my sub-domain.

I have set the `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True` in my `settings.py` and still not able to access cookies on my sub-domain.

While setting the cookie using `set_cookie` I set the to `domain = 'domain.com'`

Comment: The [settings docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#session-cookie-domain) suggest that you should have a leading dot if you want the cookie to be valid on subdomains, i.e. `'.domain.com'`. Note also the warning about making this change on a production site.

Comment: Fixed the issue. The `withCredentials = true` was missing on the client side requests to send the cookies in cross domain request.

Comment: @SuhasShelar you saved my day, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.domain.com']
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".domain.com"
```

by this, session cookies are set in all subdomains including www.

Comment: While this answer may be correct, please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issues. I tried every possible configuration of the cookies until I thought that the issue might be with the frontend.

Long story short — if you are using axios make sure you set `withCredentials: true`. [How to force credentials to every Axios request](https://flaviocopes.com/axios-credentials/)

Other libraries might have something similar.